# How to delete old Docker logs?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I'm running a python script in a docker container using docker-compose on an Ubuntu 20.04 server. I'm looking for a way to automatically delete old docker-compose logs. I specified such a structure, but the script hangs after about a week of work:

```
logging:
  driver: "json-file"
  options:
    max-size: "200k"
    max-file: "10"
```

It seems to me that this is happening because the place for logs is running out. Is this possible or is there another reason? And if this is the reason, how can I solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an external script.
First, find the container logs location with this command

```
docker container inspect  --format='{{.LogPath}}' [CONTAINER ID/NAME]
```

And then, truncate the log file with

```
truncate -s 0 /path/to/logfile
```

You can put that in a bash script and have it run automatically with cron.